# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property selectedContact of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter

I've a class Contact:

```
export class Contact
{
  public Id: string = '';
  public FirstName: string = '';
  public LastName: string = '';
  public Email: string = '';
  public Description: string = '';
  public Members: Array<User> = [];
  public Mute: boolean = false;   
}
```

I have another class SelectedContact which is inheriting this class

```
export class SelectedContact extends Contact {
    public skipMessages: number;
    public hasMessages: boolean;
    public canSendMessage: boolean;
}
```

I have a service which is to get and set the SelectedContacts

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService
{
  private contactList: Array<Contact> = [];
  private selectedContactId: string;

  public get SelectedContact(): SelectedContact
  {
    const contact: Contact = this.contactList.find((v) => v.Id === this.selectedContactId);

    return contact ? contact : null;
  }

  public set SelectedContact(value: string | Contact): void
  {
    this.selectedContactId = typeof value === 'string' ? value as string : value.Id;
  }
}
```

Then inside my component's ngOnInit(), I'm trying to set my local variable, but getting error:

```
@Component({...})
export class RightSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedContact: SelectedContact;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.selectedContact = this.contactService.SelectedContact;
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property selectedContact of [object Object] which has only a getter", in the above line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `this.selectedContact` is defined as getter in your component.

Comment: yes, this was the issue, it was present in another part of code